# Homepage without language annotation

Tags: java, html, web

A bunch of webpages exist, like Wikipedia, which have a language annotation in the URL (e.g. the German Wikipedia side is `de.wikipedia.org`). Hence, connecting to Wikipedia in multiple languages is trivial, one only need to change "de" by "en" for example. This leads to my problem. What to do if an homepage offers multiple languages, but doesn't have a language annotation in their URL?

When I connect with Java to the following homepage (http://www.hermes.admin.ch/), it is always presented in English. I found out, that English is the default language. However, they offer to change the language by clicking on the language type at the top right side. From the source code, the following code fragment shows the active language:

```
<!-- German -->
<li>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces"></script>
<a id="lang-select-form_de" href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('lang-select-form'),{'lang-select-form_de':'lang-select-form_de'},'');return false" class="inactive">Deutsch</a>
</li>

<!-- French -->
<li><a id="lang-select-form_fr" href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('lang-select-form'),{'lang-select-form_fr':'lang-select-form_fr'},'');return false" class="inactive">Français</a>
</li>

<!-- Italian -->
<li><a id="lang-select-form_it" href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('lang-select-form'),{'lang-select-form_it':'lang-select-form_it'},'');return false" class="inactive">Italiano</a>
</li>

<!-- English -->
<li class="last"><a id="lang-select-form_en" href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('lang-select-form'),{'lang-select-form_en':'lang-select-form_en'},'');return false" class="active">English</a>
</li>
```

Hence finding out, which of the languages is active, is easy. Nevertheless, I don't find out, how I can tell the side using Java to set the active language to German without clicking on their link at the top right side.

My Java connection:

```
String url = "http://www.hermes.admin.ch/onlinepublikation/index.xhtml";    
URL myURL = new URL(url);
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.connect();

InputStream is = myURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

With the above code, I get the page in English only. I want to load it in German, French and Italian too. How can I do that?

Comment: The default language is requested by your broswer and not a decision from this website.

Answer (score 0):

The page does not provide a way, to directly request a different locale with an URL. Maybe they are using locale detection to respond with the correct page, so you need to try to set your requestion locale in the request.

So, with `URLConnection`, you can set HTTP Headers, the one you need is `Accept-Language`. You need to set this to the appropriate one ('en', 'de', 'it').

For example:

```
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "de");
```

---

Some additional information: this approach should be right on track. As when I set e.g. German as my preferred language, start a new incognito window, I get the page in German. So setting the preferred language is the way to go.

Comment: Hehe, thanks, that's exactly what I thought but until know I did not succeed in doing so ;)

Comment: Thank you for the example meskobalazs, but unfortunately it does not work. The site is still in English :(

Comment: I mean the "Accept-Language" header should be used instead of Content-Language. A normal browser sends something like:  
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3

Comment: Ehm ok. I now tried it like this: myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "Accept-Language: de;q=0.6"); (I found the values here http://www.wissing.com/Blog/Sprachausswahl_Accept_Language/) but the page is still in English. I mean am I on the right way? I really don't even understand a bit from all this web stuff...

Comment: Not every website is the same. Not every website will automatically display a language requested in the headers. There is no uniform solution to this. You'll just have to figure out how this specific website stores/changes the language.

Comment: I'd try myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "de")

Answer (score 0):

The site might be setting a cookie whenever the user selects another language. You will have to provide some kind of cookie storage for your request and send a language setting request beforehand (use Chromes Network view to see whats going on when you select another language in your browser)

Comment: I've actually tried this. They do not set a cookie. The locale is managed by JSF entirely.